# Install PostGIS v2 for PostgreSQL v9.2

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I have installed the latest stable version of PostgreSQL v9.2 and I want to install the PostGIS v2 extension.

I've been searching for it for 3 days now, however can't find it.

I did however find PostGIS v2 for PostgreSQL v9.1, thanks to this site: http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/installing-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/

I'm an Ubuntu novice, I'm more accustomed to Windows.

The PostgreSQL v9.1 package doesn't work.  Where can I get the correct package?

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://apt.opengeo.org/stage/suite/v3/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages) listing it looks like there is a package named `postgresql-9.2-postgis2`.  You may have to add a new `apt` repository to the existing ones.  In this, you can find help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm having some trouble understanding how to determine what the location of the repository is. Could you please advice me?

Comment: Can't exactly test it at the moment, but I guess adding a line `deb http://apt.opengeo.org/stage/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main` to `sources.list` and running `apt-get update` would do it.  (This asumes you use the lucid version.)  If you don't succeed, I think you can get help from the opengeo.org site.

Comment: I could't got it to work so I started over with a new Ubuntu server and installed Postgresql v9.1 and PostGIS v2 and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You may try installing PostgreSQL 9.2 from repository then install PostGIS 2.0 from source using below commands:

**Install GEOS(for topology support)**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
tar xfj geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.3.9
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd..
```

**Install PostGIS 2.0**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
tar xfz postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.0.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo make comments-install
```

Source: [how to install postgresql 9.2 + postgis 2.0](http://technobytz.com/install-postgresql-9-2-postgis-2-0-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a few steps:

1. Install postgreSQL 9.x from packages;
2. Configure ubuntugis repository from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable);
3. Add the following lines to `/etc/apt/source.list` with your ubuntu version:

   > ```
   > deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu
   > YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main deb-src
   > http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu
   > YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
   > ```
4. Run the command `apt-get update`
5. Install postGIS library and all dependencies from synaptic;
6. Create a new DB and configure PostGIS spatial extension as described [here](http://www.michelebeneventi.it/installare-postgis-2-x-come-estensione-su-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) --> consider steps 2 and 3.

Comment: The links are subject to link rot, please consider adding the important substeps from them to your answer.  Thanks in advance!